# git log alias makes my terminal misbehave?

Tags: linux, git, terminal

I have the following alias set up in my git global config:

```
hist = log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=relative
```

it seems to be that this log format I've set up makes my terminal misbehave when I try to call upon it:

[image: Weird Terminal]

This doesn't seem to be the case when I call to log without the pretty format thing, I've been trying to teach myself git for the past days and it's been a bit hard on me, and this happening which I cannot explain is not making it easier.

In my opinion it seems to be a problem with my terminal instead of a git problem, what do you guys think?

Comment: I've had a similar issue before, and it was caused by the format string. I don't see the error immediately, but try simplifying your format string to narrow down the exact cause.

Comment: Seems that it has to do with the terminal column count, if I put my terminal size to full it does not happen, is there a way to stop the process without closing the terminal? I'm a bit of a linux newb.

Comment: CTRL-C kills the active process

Comment: I can't replicate this issue (using iTerm2 on OS X with `zsh`, and `git 1.7.12.4`). I'd guess it's an issue with your shell / terminal rather than with `git`, but I don't know from the given information what that issue is.